# Inconsistent spacing between tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

Does anyone know what would cause this?

[image]

[image]

I've created a custom tab layout and I'd either want the spacing or not, just consistency.  Ideally, I'd like no spacing, but I've read that may not work with Android's action bar.

This is the xml code I'm using:

```
 public class Tabs extends TabActivity {

private static final Properties properties = Properties.getInstance();
TabHost mTabHost;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabs);

    mTabHost = getTabHost();

    addTab(getString(R.string.text_tabs_1), R.drawable.listing_tab_active, new Intent(this, Main.class), R.drawable.listing_tab_inactive);
    addTab(getString(R.string.text_tabs_2), R.drawable.keyword_tab_active, new Intent(this, Keywords.class), R.drawable.keywords_tab_inactive);
    addTab(getString(R.string.text_tabs_3), R.drawable.saved_tab_active, new Intent(this, Saved.class), R.drawable.saved_tab_inactive);
}

private void addTab(String label, int drawableId, Intent intent, int imageId) 
{
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(label);

    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, getTabWidget(), false);

    ((TextView)tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.tabText)).setText(label);

     ((ImageView)tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.tabImage)).setImageResource(imageId);

    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);

    mTabHost.addTab(spec);      
}
 }
```

tabs.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:padding="0dp" 
     />

     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="0dp" 
     />

</LinearLayout>
 </TabHost>
```

tabs_bg.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="55dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/tab_bg_selector"
>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/tabImage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingBottom="18dip"
/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/tabText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="@drawable/tab_text_selector"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="12dip"
 />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

tab_bg_selector.xml

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--  Active tab -->
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_selected" />

<!--  Inactive tab -->
<item android:state_selected="false" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_unselected" />

<!--  Pressed tab -->
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_focused" />

<!--  Selected tab (using d-pad) -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_focused" />

 </selector>
```

tab_bg_selected.xml

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient android:startColor="#A8A8A8" android:centerColor="#7F7F7F" android:endColor="#696969" android:angle="-90" />

 </shape>
```

tab_bg_unselected.xml

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient android:startColor="#5C5C5C" android:centerColor="#424242" android:endColor="#222222" android:angle="-90" />

 </shape>
```

tab_bg_focused.xml

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true" android:padding="0dp">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#E77A26"
            android:endColor="#E77A26"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            color="#0F58A7" />

    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_focused="true" android:padding="0dp">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#0F58A7"
            android:startColor="#0F58A7"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            color="#0F58A7" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:padding="0dp">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#0F58A7"
            android:startColor="#0F58A7"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            color="#0F58A7" />
    </shape>
</item>
 </selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hack up your own tabs with something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"> <!-- android:padding="5dp"  -->

        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"


                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <!--<FrameLayout-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:layout_weight="1"/>-->

        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button android:id="@+id/tab1"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/tab1_selector"  />
            <Button  android:id="@+id/tab2"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/tab2_selector"  />
            <Button android:id="@+id/tab3"     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/tab3_selector"  />
            <Button android:id="@+id/tab4"    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/tab4_selector"  />
            <Button android:id="@+id/tab5" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/tab5_selector"  />

        </LinearLayout>


        <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Adding android:background="@drawable/tab_bg_selector" to TabWidget fixed the spacing:

```
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_bg_selector" 
     />
```